# How to fix excessive depth in the array results?

Tags: algorithm, graph, racket

I'm trying to convert a python implementation of the solution to this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/

```
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        ans=[]
        n=len(graph)
        def DFS(i,arr,n):
            if i==n-1:
                ans.append(arr)
                return 
            for j in graph[i]:
                DFS(j,arr+[j],n)
        DFS(0,[0],n)
        return ans
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (dfs graph i arr n result)
  (if (= i (- n 1))
      (append result (list arr))
      (map (lambda (j) (dfs graph j (append arr (list j)) n result)) (list-ref graph i))))


(define (all-paths-source-target graph)
  (dfs graph 0 '(0) (length graph) '())
  )
```

While the python implementation gives the correct answer to the input [[4,3,1],[3,2,4],[3],[4],[]] as
[[0,4],[0,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,4]], the racket implementation gives:

[[[0,4]],[[[0,3,4]]],[[[[0,1,3,4]]],[[[[0,1,2,3,4]]]],[[0,1,4]]]]

So the arrays are correct, only that they are nested in weird ways. How to adjust the racket implementation to fix this nesting?

Answer (score 0):

wrap map with `(apply append (map ...))`